# Contact form does not send all form details when js file is enabled

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

My application form sends and I am able to receive all the information the user inserts. However upon integrating the below ajax script, the form fails to send all the values from the form, i.e EMAIL ADDRESS, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME AND NOTES. In other words, I only receive the AGE, GENDER, EDUCATION AND SPECIALIZATION field values in my email.

The ajax script validates the fields and serializes the form's input and eventually sends a success message.

Please find the files: 
**contact.php**

```
<form id="apply_form" method="post" action="Processor.php">
    <input type="text" name="applyEmail" id="applyEmail" class="requiredField email" />
    <input type="text" name="applyFirstName" id="applyFirstName" class="requiredField" />
    <input type="text" name="applyLastName" id="applyLastName" class="requiredField" />
    <div class="clearfix">
        <select name="applyAge" id="applyAge" class="requiredField" >
            <option value="age">age</option>
            <option value="18-24">18 - 24</option>
            <option value="25-34">25 - 34</option>
            <option value="35 and over">35 and over</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <select name="applyGender" id="applyGender" class="requiredField" >
        <option value="gender"><?php echo _("Gender"); ?>*</option>
        <option value="male"><?php echo _("Male"); ?></option>
        <option value="female"><?php echo _("Female"); ?></option>
    </select>
   <div class="clearfix">
    <select name="applySpecialization" id="applySpecialization" class="requiredField" >
       <option value="specialization">specialization</option>
       <option value="beauty">beauty</option>
       <option value="makeup">makeup></option>
        <option value="studies">studies</option>
        <option value="art">art</option>
        <option value="theatre">theatre</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <select name="applyEducation" id="applyEducation" class="requiredField" >
        <option value="education">education</option>
        <option value="basic">basic</option>
        <option value="high">high</option>
        <option value="polytechnic">poly</option>
        <option value="masters">masters</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <textarea name="applyNotes" id="applyNotes" cols="25" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="sendApplication" name="sendApplication" value="Apply" />
```

**ajax.js**

```
if ($("#apply_form")[0]) {
        $('#apply_form').submit(function () {
            $('#apply_form .error').remove();
            $('.requiredField').removeClass('fielderror');
            $('.requiredField').addClass('fieldtrue');
            $('#apply_form span strong').remove();
            var hasError = false;
            $('#apply_form .requiredField').each(function () {
                if (jQuery.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).addClass('fielderror');
                    $('#apply_form span').html('<strong>*Please fill out all fields.</strong>');
                    hasError = true;
                } else if ($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                    if (!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
                        var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                        $(this).addClass('fielderror');
                        $('#apply_form span').html('<strong>Your email address is incorrect</strong>');
                        hasError = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            if (!hasError) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'applyProcess.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "applyFirstName" : $('#applyFirstName').val(),
                        "applyLastName" : $('#applyLastName').val(),
                        "applyEmail" : $('#applyEmail').val(),
                                                                                                "applyAge" : $('#applyAge').val(),
                                                                                                "applyGender" : $('#applyGender').val(),
                                                                                                "applySpecialization" : $('#applySpecialization').val(),
                                                                                                "applyEducation" : $('#applyEducation').val(),
                        "applyNotes" : $('#applyNotes').val(),
                        "sendApplication" : true
                    }
                }).done(function(rsp) {
                    $('#sendApplication').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#apply_form').fadeOut(500);
                    $('.contact-success').fadeIn(500);
                }).fail(function() {
                    $('#apply_form').fadeOut(500);
                    $('.contact-fail').fadeIn(500);
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
```

**processor.php**

```
<?php

include 'library.php'; // include the library file
include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name

if(isset($_POST['sendApplication'])) {
    $email = $_POST['applyEmail'];
    $fname = $_POST['applyFirstName'];
    $lname = $_POST['applyLastName'];   
    $selected_val_age = $_POST['applyAge'];    
    $selected_val_gender = $_POST['applyGender'];    
    $selected_val_specialization = $_POST['applySpecialization'];    
    $selected_val_education = $_POST['applyEducation'];
    $notes = $_POST['applyNotes'];

    function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }


    $email_message = "Applicant's Details.\n\n";
    $email_message = "<table>";
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($fname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Surname: ".clean_string($lname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .="Age: ".clean_string($selected_val_age)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Gender: ".clean_string($selected_val_gender)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Specialization: ".clean_string($selected_val_specialization)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Education Level Attained: ".clean_string($selected_val_education)."\n";
    $email_message .= "About Applicant: ".clean_string($notes)."\n";
    $email_message .= "</table>";


    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
    $mail->Host       = SMTP_HOST;
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
    $mail->Username   = SMTP_UNAME;
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PWORD; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->FromName = $lname.' '.$fname;
    $mail->From = $email;  //From address of the mail
    $mail->Subject = ("Application Form"); //Subject of your mail
    $mail->AddAddress("me@me.com");
    $mail->AddCC("me@you.com");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("me@me.com", "Man");
    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded, convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->Body = $email_message;
    $mail->AltBody = $email_message;

    $send = $mail->Send(); //Send the mails


}
?>
```

I cant figure out why the ajax script is not processing all other values though it does everything else (even returning the success message.)
Any assistance will be highly appreciated. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, i was using two identical Form ID's. everything worked accordingly after changing the forms' ID names.

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing the form, the discarding the data and trying to recreate it manually. Dont do that, just send the serialized data:

```
var formInput = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
     url: 'applyProcess.php',
     type: "POST",
     data: formInput,
     ...
```

Comment: I have tried to discard the manually created data and now, am not even receiving the emails. I have also gone further to recreate the data manually and omitted the serialize method but again, i get the email without the previous values.